# What kind of software would you use for broadcasting an event?

Tags: streaming, video-conferencing

Let's say you need to broadcast an event (like a convention or a conference, etc.). Then you are using a camera able to videotape it and send the information to your computer.

What kind of software a client and you could use to broadcast the video? The easy answer is Skype, but is there something broader than that?

- OS: Windows or Linux, doesn't matter
- More than 100 clients/people
- No price limit
- Client connecting to broadcast simultaneously: additional feature would be a plus
- Special feature of the software: appart from its basic broadcasting feature, any
- Typical use: Imagine I wanted to broadcast a TED talk to my school. I'd be there with my video camera (for instance Canon C100 or Canon VIXIA) and from that video camera to the "sofware I'm asking about" so that students would connect to the client part of that "sofware" so watch the event.

Answer (score 1):

The way we do this (and graduation, and sports events and ...) uses multiple bits -

Multiple cameras, connecting to a TriCaster mixing board, which records and encodes to send out to youtube, vimeo, wowza, or similar streaming service.

If this is a one-off, contract it all out.  If it will happen 4-5 times per year for multiple years, it may be worth buying equipment and hiring someone to do it internally